# Delete a single row from an MSSQL table from PHP

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I have the below code to list out a full list of companies on a web page.

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    echo $row['company']
}
```

What I am wanting to do is have an icon next to each of the company names so that I can delete them if need be. I tried to achieve this using the below:

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$id = $row['id'];
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    echo $row['company']. "<input type='image' name='". $id ."' 
src='img\binIcon.png'/></br>" ;
}
    if(isset($_POST[$id])){
    $delCompany = "DELETE FROM dbo.Companies WHERE id = $id";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $delCompany );
}
```

But this i could not get working, anyone have any better way of doing this?

Comment: Okay, you have name `id`, but where is the value?

Comment: `id` is pulled from the database where all the company names are stored so each company name has a corresponding `id`

Comment: if you're pulling, then you're using the wrong superglobal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT `id`, `company` FROM `YOUR TABLE` ORDER BY id";

$products = "";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)) {

    /* execute statement */
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
 mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $company);

    /* fetch values */
 while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
 $products .= "<a href='your-page.php?id=". $id ."'>".$company." | <img src='img/binIcon.png'/></a>";

    }
} 

////PRINT OUT ALL YOUR ITEMS HERE//////
echo $products;



////Delete the item//////
///Its always a good idea to double check and ask the user if they are sure that they want to delete the row in case they pressed the delete button by accident///

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$Did = $_GET['id'];
    $delCompany = "DELETE FROM dbo.Companies WHERE id='$Did'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $delCompany );
}
```

You have a few errors in your code!

for example `if(isset($_POST[$id])){`  I think you meant to write: `if(isset($_POST['id'])){`

OR

This `img\binIcon.png` should be this `img/binIcon.png`

Anyway, try my code and let me know how that goes.

Comment: It´s a good practise to parse the ID as int `$Did = intval($_GET['id']);` to avoid SQL injections

Comment: @teldri, not necessarily true. what would you do if the value of the $_GET is a string? something like $_GET['some value goes here'];

Comment: $safe_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_variable);

Comment: @teldri,  You mean to say:  `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $unsafe_variable);`    so your first comment about using intval to avoid SQL injection doesn't not apply at all time.

Comment: yes true it does not apply all the time, but in this case it does ;-) But you´re right, I just should have mentioned that people should be aware of the SQL injection risk generally...

Comment: why an mysqli_  answer? they're using a different api here.

Comment: @teldri was right about `intval($_GET['id'])`, just not about `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- they are not using anything here... the OP's code is a mess!! and clearly doesn't work for them. as for using mysqli_ I tend to use it all the times thus providing my answer based on that as well instead of trying to clean up the OP's messy code. and my code achieves what the OP's asking for.

Comment: @DavidHope Thank you for your answer, am having a look at inputting it now and will test it and let you know shortly (also i know the code is a mess but it's also a WIP)

Comment: @xjacksssss, No problem. I just made a change in the code so the `company` name is next to the `bin` image separated by a `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Please compare your code with mine, you had a few mistakes or missunderstandings in your version..

```
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        echo $row['company']. "<input type='image' name='id' value='". $row['id'] ."' 
    src='img\binIcon.png'/></br>" ;
    }
        if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $delCompany = "DELETE FROM dbo.Companies WHERE id = '".intval($_POST['id'])."'";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $delCompany );

}
```

no need to say that there should be `<form...` tags around your input

Comment: This img\binIcon.png should be this img/binIcon.png. take a note of backward slash.

Comment: But surely with this version all of the companies will have the name of `id` so if you then execute the delete then it will delete all of them correct?

Comment: You shouldn't specify `value` on input with image types:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image